# How to bind multi selection indices of an SWT list?

Tags: java, data-binding, swt, jface

I want to bind the current multiselection indices of a SWT list to my model. Ideally I would bind an int[] that represents the selected indices as returned by list.getSelectionIndices().

Is this possible using JFace Databinding?